# Reload object/iframe after logging into office365

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to write some code to reload an object which contains an embedded PowerBI report. Once the user logs in via a separate office365 login tab whcih closes after logging in. I want my page to reload to show the report.

Chrome unfortunately doesn't refresh the object compared to FireFox or Edge.

```
<div class="htmlContentDiv">
<object id="dashboard" width="75%" height="75%"
        data="https://app.powerbi.com/reportEmbed?reportId=123">
</object>
```

If I could even be pointed to a similar question I haven't found yet that would be useful.